# Split values from one column into multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have got the following query

```
SELECT mobile_no, customer_no, processing_date,
LISTAGG(maak, '-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY maak)
```

which outputs for example

```
Mobile No |User    | Date      | Maak
04343243  |1000978 | 31-JAN-14 | Cross net(mins)-4.271-66.1-LandLine(mins)-2.029-200.467
```

How can I split the values in the column Maak  based on '-' in different columns called Tariff, Amount and Usage. So the desired output in this case would be

```
Mobile No | User    | Date      | Tariff          | Amount | Usage | Tariff         | Amount | Usage
04343243  | 1000978 | 31-JAN-14 | Cross net(mins) | 4.271  | 66.1  | LandLine(mins) | 2.029  | 200.467
```

Also, I am looking for a standard code independent of the number of '-' in the row which will work for any number of '-'.

Comment: A SQL query returns a fixed number of columns, not a variable number of columns.  I don't think you can do what you want.  If you want to continue, include sample data in the question, as well as the results you want.

Comment: I have included a sample data(example) and the desired output..

Comment: You included the results from your query, not the original data.

Comment: Are you keeping the `listagg`? What do you want to happen if there are two values, which are now separated by commas instead of being in two rows? Or is that what you've shown but your `listagg` is actually using `-` as the separator? 'Any number of `-`' might be an issue, but you could maybe use a dynamic SQL pivot, or there might be an XML workaround.

Comment: Sorry I have changed my listagg to '-'. Forgot to do it